# Firebase Javascript: Securely store a password inside the database

Tags: javascript, html, security, firebase

I was wondering how to securely store a password in Firebase. I'm creating a chatting application that has different chat rooms which are private. A user needs to know the password in order to access the room of course. I was thinking about encrypting the user's inputted password using a JavaScript library, and then sending that encrypted password over to my Firebase database. Is it secure for me to do it this way?

Comment: Unless you choose a secure hashing algorithm and a salt, yes!

Comment: Use HTTPS, then there's no need to worry about sending passwords between client and server.

Comment: @Jonasw The comment is hard to make sense of as worded. Also just hashing with a salt is insufficient for passwords. – zaph 32 mins ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

**Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security.  Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `ehash`, `PBKDF2`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: Isnt that still hashing? :/

Comment: Yes and no, it may use a cryptographic hash function or not. But not a single hash that is very fast ~ 1us but ~100 ms. It also uses a random salt, generally with an HMAC or an encryption method, BCrypt which uses Blowfish. It is the difference between ns and ms of CPU utilization that counts. That create 100,000 times more work  for the attacker to brute force a password.